# How do I check whether I'm using DRI2 or DRI3 when using (GNOME) Wayland?

Tags: linux, drivers, wayland

I'm aware that in X.Org I can check whether I'm using DRI2 or DRI3 by checking the X.Org log, but what about GNOME Wayland (and other Wayland implementations, assuming there is a general way)? How do I check whether I'm using DRI2 or DRI3 in Wayland?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Infrastructure) is specific to X Windows.

If you run X software under XWayland, it cannot use DRI2.  XWayland only supports DRI3.

See: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=101681